# Preventing function to not stop at first `return` within the `for` loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a function to check for the "negative", "positive" and "zero" value in the list. Below is my function:

```
def posnegzero(nulist):
    for x in nulist:
        if x > 0:
            return "positive"
        elif x < 0:
            return "negative"
        else:
            return "zero"
```

But when I run this function, it stops after checking the value of the first number in the list. For example:

```
>>> posnegzero([-20, 1, 2, -3, -5, 0, 100, -123])
"negative"
```

I want it to continue for the entire list. In the above function, if I change every instance of `return` to `print`, then it does what it should but now I don't want it to say `None` when the function is complete. Any ideas of where I went wrong?

Comment: your indentations are wrong.

Comment: Aren't you expected to build a list and return it? Search "list comprehension"

Comment: The difference between `print` and `return` is quite significant. You should be clearer what you want to achieve with the output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) stops the control flow of your function and returns back the flow. You may use [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield) here which will convert your function into a [*generator*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator). For example:

```
def posnegzero(nulist):
    for x in nulist:
        if x > 0:
            yield "positive"
        elif x < 0:
            yield "negative"
        else:
            yield "zero"
```

It will yield the next result every time [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) is called on the returned object:

```
>>> result = posnegzero([-20, 1, 2, -3, -5, 0, 100, -123])
>>> next(result)
'negative'
>>> next(result)
'positive'
>>> next(result)
'positive'
```

Or you may get all the result at once as:

```
>>> result = posnegzero([-20, 1, 2, -3, -5, 0, 100, -123])
>>> list(result)
['negative', 'positive', 'positive', 'negative', 'negative', 'zero', 'positive', 'negative']
```

You can also iterate it using `for` loop. `for` loop repeatedly calls the [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) method until it receives a [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) exception. For example:

```
for result in posnegzero([-20, 1, 2, -3, -5, 0, 100, -123]):
    print(result)

# which will print
negative
positive
positive
negative
negative
zero
positive
negative
```

For more information on `yield`, please refer: [*What does the “yield” keyword do?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/2063361)

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is returning immediately on the first list element

Personally, I would do like this - define the function for a value only. Not a list. Run the function over each value of the list

(Python 3)

```
def posnegzero(x):
    if x > 0:
        return "positive"
    elif x < 0:
        return "negative"
    else:
        return "zero"

print(list(map(posnegzero, [-20, 1, 2, -3, -5, 0, 100, -123])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just build your results in a list:

```
def posnegzero(lst):
    result = []

    for x in lst:
        if x > 0:
            result.append("positive")
        elif x < 0:
            result.append("negative")
        else:
            result.append("zero")

    return result
```

Which works as follows:

```
>>> posnegzero([-20, 1, 2, -3, -5, 0, 100, -123])
['negative', 'positive', 'positive', 'negative', 'negative', 'zero', 'positive', 'negative']
```

Or even with a conditional list comprehension:

```
def posnegzero(lst):
    return ["positive" if x > 0 else "negative" if x < 0 else "zero" for x in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
d=["pos" if i>0  else "neg"if i<0  else "zero" for i in [-20, 1, 2, -3, -5, 0, 100, -123]]
```

output

> ['neg', 'pos', 'pos', 'neg', 'neg', 'zero', 'pos', 'neg']

Comment: You forgot zero condition, which is not negative